# I am using Selenium with java , and I want to do the setup of CI ustin Gitlab CI

Tags: selenium, gitlab-ci

I have been trying to find out how should I execute the Selenium Test (Java) using gitlab CI

1. I have created an automation framework and I am able to run the maven project via jenkins
2. I wanted to run the same maven project with the help of gitlab ci runner
3. My Code will be available on git and just need to trigger the execution as a when developer checks in the code

Please help me out with this setup, I have been trying to find out the solution but couldn't figure out any

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read about jeknins and gitlab hooks here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html


, In general, these hooks "follows" any push you perform to you gitlab repository, and run the desired build on them, including pulling the latest code.

Comment: Please suggest , if this can be done without the use of jenkins

Comment: My knowledge is for webhooks with Jenkins only. I believe there are few similar CI tools that will do the job. I know from my experience that it works very well using Jenkins.